# Laravel hasManyThrough - save doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through

```
table groups
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);

table users
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    ...
);

table user_groups
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    group_id int not null,
    ...
);
```

In my Group model, i've a hasManyThrough relation to access users through user_groups linking table.

```
class Group
{
    function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('\App\Models\User', '\App\Models\UserGroup', 'group_id', 'id', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

In my controller :

```
$user = User::find(2);
$group->users[] = $user;
$group->save();
```

So `$group->users` is a collection and i can add my user but it's not saving.

How to add record on a `hasManyThrough` relation ?

Comment: This looks more like `belongsToMany` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) instead of `hasManyThrough`. Try that — you may have to specify the columns as shown in the docs and will use `attach()` instead of `save()`. Also, in your `user_groups` pivot, you may not need the `id` column.

Comment: You right, can you make an answer, which i can mark as resolved ?

Answer (score -1):

Sure you can do this:

```
// Find an existing User record
$user = App\User::find(2);

// Creates a new group instance 
$group = new App\group(['name' => 'shokry']);

// effectively sets $group->User_id to 2 then saves the instance to the DB
$user->groups()->save($group);
```

models

```
class User extends Model
{
  public function groups()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Group::class);
  }
}

class Group extends Model
{
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
  }
}
```

Comment: You've provided an example for `HasMany` not `HasManyThrough`